# How to make multiple calls to the Firebase more secure? - swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So I have a "Delete account" button in my app and when the user taps it, it deletes the Auth account as well as 3 other Firestore documents. I am nervous that one function might succeed while others might fail. How do I ensure that if one function fails, all fail?

```
    func deleteUser () {
        let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

        Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: { (error) in
            if error != nil { return }
            else {
                Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(currentUser!.uid).delete { (error) in
                    if error != nil { return }
                    else {
                        Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").document(currentUser!.uid).delete { (error) in
                            if error != nil { return }
                            else {
                                transitionToHomeScreen()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should probably delete the documents before deleting the user.  If you delete the user first, there is a possibility that the user might lose the ability to delete their documents, depending on what your security rules allow.

Second, there is no way to ensure transactional consistency between Firebase Auth and Firestore (nor between any two Firebase products).  There is no way to automatically roll back changes to Auth if something fails in Firestore, nor the other way around.  If you need to roll back a change, you have to write code for that.

If you want to ensure that more than one documents are deleted at the same time, you should use a [transaction or batch write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to ensure that either all or none of the documents are deleted together.